# how to add a cv section in job portal website with php?

Tags: php, html, css, portal

i want to  create a job portal website with PHP and add a CV section on it for example when the user want to apply for a job he will click on the cv section section and fill the form and he will click on submit bottom which will sent to the administrator and the administrator will have the possibility to download the CV in an PDF format .how can i do that with php?

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Code the whole process or use existing services that can provide CV or Pro Profile.

Viadeo, DoYouBuzz (Linkedin doesn't offer a great API for this) or parse a Doc / PDF with solution like Sovren parsing.

You ask for a whole project, you won't find this out of the box.

Comment: i am not asking for a whole project actually i have create cv as  a contact form for the user to fill it and submit it but the problem is when the user submit the form in the admin page i can receive only as one row with the users details but i want when the user submit the form i want to download it as PDF so i can print it i think you understand